# Where to manage an email account set up through Microsoft Small Business?

Tags: outlook.com, microsoft

I've redesigned a website for a client and am soon to set it live. However, his business emails appear to be hosted with Hotmail and I need to create a couple of new email accounts. He has told me that he originally used Microsoft Small Business to create the accounts, however it was then replaced by Office 365.

I've tried logging into Office 365 with his email login details and can't find anywhere to manage email accounts. I also can't find any guides on how to do so on their help pages or even on Google.

Could it be I'm looking in the wrong place?

I'm familiar with how to do this kind of thing on Google Apps, but I didn't even realise there was a Microsoft equivalent until now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go with outlook.com. They do have support for custom domains. Just head to http://www.domains.live.com/ and sign up. You will get all Microsoft services for your domain.